# R add legend to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot several densities, where the legend should reveal the parameters for each density function. Unfortunately, `ggplot2` does not include the legend (which is weird, in the tutorial it did...)

**Generate data:**

```
x <- seq(from=-5, to=5, by=0.1)
y1 = dlaplace(x,0,0.5)
y2 = dlaplace(x,0,1)
y3 = dlaplace(x,0,2)
df = data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)
```

**Plot**

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(data= df, aes(y=y1), color="red")+
  geom_line(data= df,aes(y=y2), color="blue")+
  geom_line(data= df,aes(y=y3), color="green")+
  ggtitle("Gamma distribution density function") +ylab("density")+ xlab("x")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

I am new to `ggplot`, and the following threads seemed related but unfortunately did not help me solve it ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499345/add-legend-to-ggplot2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267081/ggplot2-missing-legend-and-how-to-add))

Comment: Instead of adding three line layers to your plot you should reshape your data from wide to long, add a single `geom_line()` and then map the resulting "key" variable to the `color` aesthetic - this is done inside of `aes()`. You can find more infos here: [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)

Comment: okay, but wasnt the point of `ggplot` to work with dataframes?  I mean it should be able to handle wide, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a legend in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573544/generating-a-legend-in-ggplot2)

Comment: The point is to work with dataframes in long format.

Comment: Yes, the point is to work with data frames, but what sets `ggplot2` apart is the "grammar of graphics" in its name. The general `ggplot` paradigm is that you're mapping variables to aesthetics, such as groups of observations mapped to colors. If you've followed tutorials, they probably all did things this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Markus suggested, you'll need to convert your data to long format by meting it. Use `melt` function from `reshape2`. It should look something like this:

```
plotdf <- as.data.frame(t(df))
plotdf$var <- rownames(plotdf)
plotdf <- melt(plotdf[-c(1),], id.vars = "var")
print(ggplot(plotdf, aes(value, variable, colour = var)) + geom_point()+ scale_y_discrete(breaks=seq(0, 2, by = 0.5)) +
      ggtitle("Gamma distribution density function") +ylab("density")+ xlab("x")+
        theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
        guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)))
```

Output:

[image: Here's the output plot]

Can format the plot more using other `ggplot` features.
Check this: [How to melt R data.frame and plot group by bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345427/how-to-melt-r-data-frame-and-plot-group-by-bar-plot)

Comment: what is the best way to change labels from y1 to say "\alpha = 1"

Comment: Before melting the data, change the variable names as you want. Here, it'd be the new column 'var'. After crating it, replace 'y1' and then melt & plot. That should do it.